# How can I rewrite for loop to change string to int/double?

Tags: java

I am writing in java for school, the lowest and highest integers from user input (changed from string). I cannot get it to compile due to "bad operand types for binary operator '>'" and "incompatible types: String cannot be converted to double" on lines 36-39 (there are some odd things for the class)

```
public class average2{

// accept string args
public static void main( String[] args ){

    //initialize variables 
    double x = 0;
    double temp = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    double avg = 0;
    double highest = 0;
    double lowest = 0;

    System.out.print("java average ");
    for(String arg:args){
        System.out.print(arg);
        System.out.print(" ");
        //x = Double.parseDouble(args[ i ]);

    }

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Average Program. It is rather average.");

        // add numbers
        for( int i = 0; i< args.length; i++ ){      
            // convert string to either double or int 
            x = Double.parseDouble(args[ i ]);
            temp = ( x + sum);
            sum = temp; 
        }

        //find highest value
        for( int i = 1; i< args.length; i++ ){
            x = Double.parseDouble(args[ i ]);
            if(args[i] > highest)
                highest = args[i];
            else if(args[i] < lowest)
                lowest = args[i];
            //display answer
            System.out.println( "The highest given value: " + highest);
            System.out.println( "The lowest given value: " + lowest);
        }   

        if ( args.length > 0 ){

            // do math add numbers divide by length
            avg = sum / args.length;

            // display answer
            System.out.println( "The average is: " + avg);
        }

            // test for null input
        else if( args.length == 0 ){
            System.out.println( "Usage java average X (where X is a list of integers) ");
        }
}   
}
```

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you don't need `temp`.  Instead of writing `temp = (x+sum); sum = temp;`, you can just write `sum += x;` which adds the value of `x` onto the value of `sum`.

Answer (score 1):

Here, you parse the string to a double:

```
x = Double.parseDouble(args[ i ]);
```

but then, on the very next line, you try to compare the string to a number:

```
if(args[i] > highest)
```

Use `x` instead:

```
if(x > highest)
```

Answer (score 0):

> "error: bad operand types for binary operator '<'"

This is because you are trying to compare `args[i]`, a string, to `highest`, a double. You already converted `args[i]` to a double, i.e. `x`. Make sure you use `x` in your comparison i.e. `if(x > highest)`.

> "error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to double"

Again, you forgot to use your new double `x`. Make sure you use `x` in your assignments, e.g. `highest = x;`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using java 8 you can get all the stats in one line...

```
DoubleSummaryStatistics doubleSummaryStatistics = Arrays.stream(args).mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble).summaryStatistics();
```

A full code example is

```
public static void main( String[] args ){
    DoubleSummaryStatistics doubleSummaryStatistics = Arrays.stream(args).mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble).summaryStatistics();
    System.out.println(doubleSummaryStatistics.getMin());
    System.out.println(doubleSummaryStatistics.getMax());
    System.out.println(doubleSummaryStatistics.getAverage());
    System.out.println(doubleSummaryStatistics.getSum());
}
```